# AG-GRID & AngularJS - How to edit data externally

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I am working on a single page application using Agularjs, UI-Router and AG-GRID. I can't figure out how to update AG-GRID's data from an external form.

Let me explain, from the AG-GRID data table, I added button that would grab the row data and transfert it to my form page. The form page would then populate with the data correctly. Once in the form page if I try to edit the data and go back to my main page (where I have AG-GRID) I dont see any changes.

I tried doing the $scope.gridOptions.api.refreshCells(); This doesent seem to do anything nor does it generate any errors.

This is what my setup looks like so far:

Main_controller:

```
App.controller('Main_Controller', function ($scope, $http, $filter, $timeout, $mdDialog, $q, $resource, $interval, $mdSidenav, $state, Service) {

    var Buttons = function(params) {
        return '<md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Edit" ng-click="Edit(data)"> <md-icon class="material-icons">mode_edit</md-icon> </md-button>'';
    }

    var columnDefs = [
    { cellRenderer: Buttons, width: 165 },
    { headerName: "Data1", field: "Data1"},
    { headerName: "Data2", field: "Data2"}, 
    ];

    $scope.gridOptions_incident = {
        columnDefs: columnDefs,
        domLayout: 'autoHeight',
        enableFilter: true,
        enableColResize: true,
        enableSorting: true,
        pagination: true,
        paginationPageSize:25,
        animateRows: true,
        headerHeight: headerHeight,
        rowHeight:rowHeight,
        angularCompileRows : true,  
        enableCellChangeFlash: true,
        debug: true,
        rowData: Service.get_data()
    };  

    $scope.Edit = function(data){
        Service.current_incident(data);
        $state.go('OPEN_ExternalForm');
    };  

});
```

Service:

```
GDI_App.factory('Service', function($http, $q, $timeout, $mdDialog, $resource, $window) {
    return{

        get_data: function(){
            var example_data = [
               { "Data1": "123123", "Data2": "15437"  },
               { "Data1": "432234", "Data2": "146"  },
               { "Data1": "45654", "Data2": "3534"  },
               { "Data1": "76587", "Data2": "78978"  },
               { "Data1": "2342", "Data2": "5345878"  },
               { "Data1": "178", "Data2": "34534"  },
               { "Data1": "173838", "Data2": "354534"  },
            ];
            return example_data             
        }
        current_incident: function(data){
          Current.Data = data;
          return Current.Data
        }

    }
});
```

Form Controller:

```
GDI_App.controller('Form_Controller', function ($scope, $http, $filter, $timeout, $mdDialog, $q, $resource, $interval, $mdSidenav, Service) {

    $scope.Current.Data = Service.current_incident();
    $scope.Submit = function(){

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: REST_URL,
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",                 
            headers: HEADER_DATA,
            data: $scope.Current.Data
        });   

    }

});
```

Form HTML:

```
I have a very basic HTML form:

<div ng-controller="Form_Controller">
    Data1: <input ng-model="Current.Data.Data1">
    Data2: <input ng-model="Current.Data.Data2">
    <button ng-click="Submit()" type="button">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Im not quite sure what im missing. My end goal is to be able to edit the data from an external data and then have it synced up on the AG-Grid.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: In order to maintain the client in sync with the backend, wouldn't you edit the row (in your form), submit the changes to the backend and then redirect to the ag-grid page which would re-fetch the entire collection of rows? I'm asking this because I imagine that refetching the latest data would also update your grid.

Comment: I have a large form with about 20-25 inputs which are synced with my table. I wouldnt make sense to edit this in a row format. I created a nice neat form that organizes everything and then I want it to sync with the table afterwards.

Comment: I completely understand that and wasn't suggesting not using a form.
What I was wondering was regarding which points in this interaction does the server get updated and the fact that the grid should reload the latest data every time it's displayed ... which I think would resolve your issue besides providing solid logic

Comment: Ah gotcha, read too fast. The idea would to sumbit the changes to the backend first and then locally update or sync the row (on the ag-grid) on submit. Its the local update /syncing part i cant seem to understand how to get it to work.  i would prefer avoiding reloading the entire data from backend to refresh one row.

Comment: Updated the code to match closer to my situation.

Comment: I know I am going further down on an offtopic avenue, but how can you be sure that no other data has been updated while User_1 was updating a row? User_1 is constantly working on outdated info; what if they just load the page, update 1 row, save and try to update another row ... isn't the 2nd row going to be severely outdated and could've changed in the meanwhile, leading User_1 to try to update an outdated version of record which would (hopefully) result in a failure?

Comment: It’s not a problem in my case. I setup an auto refresh of the data (fetches data via backend) and modifications happen less frequently than creating new data. We have a very small group of users, they talk to each other to make sure no 2 users update the same record.

Comment: Ok, makes sense! thanks for answering :) Have you tried all these? https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/

Comment: Finally figured it out, it wasent an AG-Grid issue it was an Agularjs issue. I tought controller are automatically synced when connected to a service but its not. Had to setup a sort of manual databind between the controllers so they would sync.

Answer (score 1):

u can update cell data like this:

```
  var rowNode = $scope.gridOptions_incident.api.getRowNode(id);
  rowNode.setDataValue('Data2', 'newData');
```